# Issues in printing time series graph from pandas dataframe

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have a DataFrame object with a datetime as index:

```
In [210]:
f
f.plot(legend=True)

Out[210]:
                         user_time  sys_time  wait_io_time
date_time                                             
2012-11-01 08:59:27          3         1             0
2012-11-01 08:59:32          0         0             0
2012-11-01 08:59:37         20         2             1
2012-11-01 08:59:42          0         0             0
2012-11-01 08:59:47          0         0             0
```

f.plot() causes this error:

```
-> 1367     plot_obj.generate()
--> 674         self._make_plot()
-> 1000             self._make_ts_plot(data, **self.kwds)
---> 81     left, right = _get_xlim(ax.get_lines())
--> 220         left = min(x[0].ordinal, left)
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'ordinal'
```

I do see one line graph, displaying values from the user_time data, so suspecting that the data values from sys_time may be causing the issue. Following suggestion from https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1737, I installed a newer version of matplotlib (1.1.1) but no luck, and plotting fails on the data from the bug url as well.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? I would recommend upgrading to the latest stable version of this too! (This plots fine for me on `0.10` with matplotlib `1.1.1`.)

Comment: Seems I forgot to restart the ipython notebook after upgrading matplotlib, or did not reload matplotlib. Once I restarted the notebook, things are working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work with latest matplotlib library installed. I forgot to restart the ipython notebook process or reload the matplotlib after I upgraded it.

Comment: thanks, waiting for the SO-mandated initial time lag before I can accept my own answer.